# How to know which module currently load in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

I am new in Zend Framework, I go through documents which is provided on 
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/in-depth-guide/first-module.html

but still I am not understanding ZF2 folder Structure and also few below points.

1) How does zf2 know which module will load first?

2) How to know about currently loaded module in zf2?

Please help me to understand the Zend Framework2.

Answer (score 1):

See your `/config/application.config.php` section `modules`.
They will be loaded in the direction from top to bottom.

Loaded modules:

```
$manager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ModuleManager');
$modules = $manager->getLoadedModules();
```

Comment: Thanks :)
But how to know which module(s) of that array is loaded currently?